how to change array of object based on condition using javascript
I would like to know how to shift based on field that contains numeric string and normal string.
so, if numeric string value then shift to end of array, rest remain same
Tried
 const sortData = arrobj.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      const sortA = a.cn;
      const sortB = b.cn;
      
      if(!isNaN(sortA)) {
        return -1;
      }
      if(!isNaN(sortB)) {
        return 1;
      }
      return sortA.localeCompare(sortB);
    });
    console.log("sortData", sortData);

var arrobj=[
  {cn: '99'}
  {cn: 'SG'},
  {cn: 'IN'}
]

expecteded output
[
  {cn: 'SG'},
  {cn: 'IN'},
  {cn: '99'}
]



What's the expected result if you have multiple numeric strings, eg: cn: '88, do the numeric strings need to be sorted? Do the non-numeric strings need to be sorted as well, or just keep their relative positions from the original array?

Second Update
KLASANGUI pointed out that there's no sorting just moving the numbers. See Example A.
Example A


const shiftNum = (arr) => {
  // Define an array for numbers and an array for strings
  let num = [], str = [];
  // Add numbers to num and strings to str
  arr.forEach(chr => {
    if (!isNaN(chr.cn)) {
      num.push(chr);
    } else {
      str.push(chr);
    }
  });
  // Merge str and num arrays into one array
  return [...str, ...num];
};

const arrObj=[{cn: '99'}, {cn: 'SG'}, {cn: '666'}, {cn: 'IN'}, {cn: '1'}];

console.log("shiftNum =" + JSON.stringify(shiftNum(arrObj)));



The OP had many syntactical errors, get in the habit of using a tool like JSHint. The order you want is just in reverse so use .reverse() Array method on the array after it's sorted or just switch the parameters of .localeCompre(). Also, .localeCompare() doesn't handle numbers correctly, so I updated to reflect that. Details are commented in example.
Example B


const sortData = (arr) => {
  // Define an array for strings and numbers
  let str = []; num = [];
  // Add strings to str and numbers to num
  arr.forEach(chr => {
    if (isNaN(chr.cn)) {
      str.push(chr);
    } else {
      num.push(chr);
    }
  });
  // Sort strings with localCompare() (reverse params b then a)
  str = str.sort((a, b) => b.cn.localeCompare(a.cn)); //
  // Sort numbers by whether the difference is negative or positive 
  num = num.sort((a, b) => b.cn - a.cn); //
  // Merge str and num into one array
  return [...str, ...num]; //
  /**
   * Alternative using .reverse() change the denoted lines:
   *    a.cn.localeCompare(b.cn)
   *    a.cn - b.cn
   *    [...str, ...num].reverse()
   */   
};

const arrObj = [{cn: '99'}, {cn: 'SG'}, {cn: 'IN'}, {cn: '1'}, {cn: '666'}];

console.log("sortData =", JSON.stringify(sortData(arrObj)));




You misunderstood the sorting order required: "if numeric string value then shift to end of array, rest remain same" (from OP). There's no sorting between both strings or both numbers...

Updated answer, thanks @KLASANGUI

You're welcome.

Hmm... I think that you just need to add extra conditions to your ifs...


const arrobj =
[
  {cn: '99'},
  {cn: 'SG'},
  {cn: 'IN'},
];

const sortData = arrobj.sort
(
  ( $1, $2 ) =>
  {
    const $1first = -1;
    const $2first = 1;
    const $equal = 0;
    
    if ( isNaN( parseFloat($1.cn) ) && ! isNaN( parseFloat($2.cn) ) )
    {
      // Only $1.cn is non-numeric. So, $2.cn is numeric.
      return $1first;
    }
    
    if ( isNaN( parseFloat($2.cn) ) && ! isNaN( parseFloat($1.cn) ) )
    {
      // Only $2.cn is non-numeric. So, $1.cn is numeric.
      return $2first;
    }
    
    // As requested, there's no sorting between both numbers or both strings...
    return $equal;
    // Remove the line above if you wish to order like below:
    
    // But you can sort them separatly... However you like...
    
    if ( isNaN( parseFloat($1.cn) ) && isNaN( parseFloat($2.cn) ) )
    {
      // Both $1.cn and $2.cn are non-numeric. Ascending order.
      return String($1.cn).localeCompare($2.cn);
    }
    
    else
    {
      // Both $1.cn and $2.cn are numeric. Descending order.
      return String($1.cn).localeCompare($2.cn) * -1;
    }
  }
);
console.log("sortData =", sortData);



